# Reversing Hisense TV Firmware

Tags: decompilation, linux, arm, unpacking

I am looking for methods to get root on my Linux smart tv. Anyone have any ideas, in order to try extract the kernel config. Hisense is no help when asking for GPL source.

I ran metasploit against it and had no luck, it did find some open ports for upnp and something called twonkymedia but I was not able to get anywhere with that.

I have a Hisense LTDN50K220GWUS (Hisense 50H5GB) Smart TV that is running what appears to be a customized version of "Opera TV OS"
Running on "Linux-3.0.13" and is using uboot, I tried connecting a usb keyboard to the ports and pounding escape and other buttons
but that didn't get me anywhere.

Using Binwalk I was able to extract so info from a rom firmware image:
[binwalk output](http://dl-1.va.us.xda-developers.com/3/3/9/0/9/9/1/binwalk.txt?key=tYzIcmGKTrH3OtBCCkWz6w&ts=1446066314)

Comment: Link to binwalk output is dead. Providing a link to a full firmware image will also help.

Comment: Working for me!

Answer (score 5):

My achievements.
I added to the startup telnetd, and ftpd.
I found cifs.ko. kernel module And now added to mount network folders on boot. It works faster than dlna, in addition, I was able to solve the problem with the display of some of the file names in the Russian keyboard layout that used to be displayed as question marks....
See my research on the link
http://openlgtv.org.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=170280

Answer (score 3):

Use binwalk to extract *rootfs*, then search for file `passwd` in */etc/*
You will discover every users available. Look for root user, this should look like:

```
root:x3FrTg6uYT7.:0:0:root:/:/bin/sh
```

Recover the `x3FrTg6uYT7`string and give it to John the ripper software. This one will try to brute force the password. Once done you will need to find a debug port on your TV.

I advise you to take a look at this [link](http://www.devttys0.com/2012/11/reverse-engineering-serial-ports/).
Finally connect your [RS232 com cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008AGDTA4), power on your tv and wait for a shell asking for root password :)

Have fun.

Useful links:

http://cities.lk.net/lost_password.htm

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file/

Comment: Unfortunately there is no password for root in there, nor is there a /etc/shadow, I am trying to get the sources from the manufacturer. If not I will have to see if there is a method to dump from the TV.

Comment: Is ther any `root` account ? Can you copy/paste the line ?

Comment: root:x:0:0:root:/basic:/bin/sh

Comment: As you may know `x` means that the password is in `/etc/shadow`. But as you said there is no shadow file, that's quite strange ... However, shadow file is not obliged to be in `/etc/shadow` if I remember well, I propose you to do something like `grep -R "root:" /path/to/your/rootfs` to find the shadow file.